# LLDB is not setting breakpoints at the correct line

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

This should server to illustrate the problem.  I was originally trying to set the breakpoints in Xcode, but observed that the same problem happened when I set them on the command line of LLDB:

```
(lldb) list /Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Source/BalLGame.h:300
   300         }
   301     }
   302 
   303     void handleCollision(const Object & other) override
   304     {
   305         if (other.getComponentID() == "paddle")
   306         {
   307             auto & paddle = dynamic_cast<const Paddle&>(other);
   308 
   309             auto positionInPaddle = paddle.getLocalPoint(this, getLocalBounds().getCentre());
   310             auto normal = paddle.getNormal(positionInPaddle.getX());
```

Now let me set a breakpoint at line 305.

```
(lldb) break set -f /Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Source/BalLGame.h -l 305
Breakpoint 4: where = Buzz`Ball::getDamage() const + 12 at BalLGame.h:341, address = 0x00000001000018ac
```

But bugger - it's now at line 341.

Here is line 341:

```
(lldb) list /Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Source/BalLGame.h:340
   340 
   341     int getDamage() const { return damage; }
   342 
   343     void tick() override
   344     {
   345         setBounds(getBounds().translated(getDirectionVector().x, getDirectionVector().y));
   346         angle += deltaAngle;
   347     }
   348 
   349     bool isKilled() override { return killed; }
   350
```

And we have debugging symbols:

```
(lldb) script lldb.target.module['/Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Builds/MacOSX/build/Debug/Buzz.app/Contents/MacOS/Buzz'].GetNumCompileUnits()
19
```

Any ideas what to check next?  It's a debug build...I've just upgraded to the latest Xcode version, but it was failing in Xcode 6 as well in exactly the same way.

PS. Here are the lovely compiler options:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings **-O0** -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -D_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DJUCER_XCODE_MAC_F6D2F4CF=1 -DJUCE_APP_VERSION=1.0.0 -DJUCE_APP_VERSION_HEX=0x10000 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Buzz-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Buzz-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Buzz-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Buzz-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Builds/MacOSX/build/Debug/include -I../../JuceLibraryCode -I../../../juce/modules -I/Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/DerivedSources -Wreorder -F/Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Builds/MacOSX/build/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BalLGame.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BalLGame.dia -c /Users/jim/Code/breakout-juce/Source/BalLGame.cpp -o /Users/jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Buzz-gymosgfspfkofkhbahhngwelyhbv/Build/Intermediates/Buzz.build/Debug/Buzz.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BalLGame.o

Comment: Have you tried a full rebuild? Often helps in such strange situations

Comment: Does gdb work better? The goal would be to find out if clang generated bad debug info, or if lldb is badly using it.

Comment: @Codeguard  tried that ...:/ and deleted all the 'derived data' and rebuilt just in case!

Comment: @Marc - that's not a bad plan actually though I've not used gdb with clang since apple dropped it I'll see if I can get that working.

Answer (score 2):

If you set a breakpoint on a line of source code that doesn't generate any executable code (e.g. a comment, a #ifdef'ed out line, an non-exported function that never gets used) lldb will move the breakpoint to the next source line that generates executable code, which may well be in a different function.

Can't tell for sure from your source clips, but if getDamage is the next function after handleCollision, then the breakpoint motion would be explained if no code was emitted for handleCollision.  If you do:

```
(lldb) image lookup -n ClassName::handleCollision
```

or if you want to consult something outside lldb:

```
$ nm <Binary> | grep handleCollision
```

do they show there is actually a symbol for that function?

Comment: Well, the code in handleCollision is actually running, otherwise my game wouldn't be working as well as it is!.  However  I'll double check because you can never be too careful ... or rather I could always be being idiotic :)

Comment: I added an asm ("int $3");  where I was attempting to insert the break point.  The debugger then stops in the correct location.  Unfortunately I need to let the code run a while before inserting the breakpoint so I still need to resolve this issue ... but it looks like the code exists at least!

Comment: Since the original code is in a .h file, the code for the function is going to get generated in some other .cpp file's .o file.  Generally more than one if it gets used in more than one place, and then the linker will have to unique those many instances down to one when it makes the final binary.  Somewhere in that process the line table information for the function is getting lost.  I can't guess how this could happen without poking at the project.  If this is something you can make available, please file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Note, as a workaround, if you have a BalLGame.cpp you could try moving the implementation of the function there.

Comment: Jim - great stuff thank you.  I'll try both the bug report and the move-it-to-the implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Xcode to the latest version,if you use Xcode 7.1 or below there could be many bugs i'm using Xcode 7.1.1 and didn't got any problems

Comment: Already upgraded I'm afraid ... same result actually before and after the upgrade.  thank you though!

Comment: try this as well maybe it helped `xcode-select --install`